# Find the max value of $f(z)=|z^3-z+2|$ on the unit circle $|z|=1 $

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, maxima-minima

**Question No $1$**

> Find the maximum value of $f(z)=|z^3-z+2|$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$

**Solution**
Let $z:=\exp(\text{i}\theta)$ and $t:=\cos(\theta)$.  Then,
$$\begin{align}|z^3-z+2|^2&=\Big|\big(\cos(3\theta)-\cos(\theta)+2\big)^2+\text{i}\big(\sin(3\theta)-\sin(\theta)\big)\Big|^2
\\&=4\cos(3\theta)-2\cos(2\theta)-4\cos(\theta)+6
\\&=4(4t^3-3t)-2(2t^2-1)-4t+6
\\&=16t^3-4t^2-16t+8=:g(t)\,.
\end{align}$$
Thus, we want to maximize $g(t)$ subject to $t\in[-1, 1]$.  Note that
$$g'(t)=48t^2-8t-16=8(6t^2-t-2)=8(2t+1)(3t-2)\,.$$
That is, optimizing points of $g(t)$ in $[-1, 1]$ are $t=-\dfrac12$, $t=\dfrac23$, and the boundary points $t\in\{-1, 1\}$.

Note that $g(-1)=4$, $g(1)=4$, $g\left(-\dfrac12\right)=13$, and $g\left(\dfrac23\right)=\dfrac{8}{27}$.  We conclude that the minimum of $g(t)$ on $[-1,+1]$ is $\dfrac{8}{27}$, which is attained when $t=\dfrac23$, whereas the maximum of $g(t)$ on $[-1, 1]$ is $13$, which is attained when $t=-\dfrac12$.  Translating this back to $\theta$, we see that $\theta=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\theta=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$ satisfy $\cos(\theta)=-\dfrac12$.  Thus,
$$z=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{3}\right)=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2}\text{ and }z=\exp\left(\frac{4\pi\text{i}}{3}\right)=\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2}$$
maximize $|z^3-z+2|$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$.  The maximum value of $|z^3-z+2|$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$ is $\sqrt{13}$.

Similarly, the minimum value of $|z^3-z+2|$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$ is $\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{27}}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}}$. The minimum is attained when
$$z=\frac{2+\sqrt{5}\text{i}}{3}\text{ and }z=\frac{2-\sqrt{5}\text{i}}{3}\,.$$
(This happens when $\theta=\text{arccos}\left(\dfrac23\right)$ and when $\theta=2\pi-\text{arccos}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)$.)

**Doubt: Why can't i apply traingle inequality here?  which is $||Z_1|-|Z_2||\leq |Z_1+Z_2| \leq |Z_1|+|Z_2|$**

**Question No $2$**

> Let $f(z)=2z^2-1.$Then what is  the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ on the unit disc $D=\{z \in \mathbb C:|z|\leq 1\}$ ?

**Solution**$|f(z)|=|2z^2-1|\leq 2|z|^2+1\leq 2+1=3.$  So, is $3$  the maximum value of $|f(z)|?$ Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

**We get answer using triangle inequality here**

**Question No $3$**

> How do you find the maximum value of $|z^2 - 2iz+1|$ given that $|z|=3$, using triangle inequality?

**Solution**
After playing with the triangle inequality for a while, we may realize that we are not going to arrive at the maximum without absurd ingenuity, so we consider other methods:

- [Calculus I: stationary points][1]:  Substitute $z = 3 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$, find real and imaginary parts and construct the modulus as the sum of the squares of those parts, giving (simplified) $$\sqrt{2} \left( \sqrt{59 + 9 \cos(2 \theta) - 48 \sin(\theta)} \right) \text{.}$$  Differentiate this with respect to $\theta$, giving $$ -\frac{3\sqrt{2} \left( 8 \cos(\theta) + 3 \sin(2\theta) \right)}{\sqrt{59 + 9 \cos(2 \theta) - 48 \sin(\theta)}} \text{.}$$  Set this equal to zero and solve for $\theta$, giving $\pm \pi/2$ as locations of stationary points.  Evaluating the substituted polynomial at these two angles gives $-2$ and $-14$, so the maximum modulus of the polynomial on the circle of radius $3$ is $14$.
- [Lagrange Multipliers][2]:  Construct $|z^2 + 2\mathrm{i} z + 1|
   - \lambda(|z| - 3)$ then take derivatives with respect to $z$ and
  $\lambda$, set those simultaneously equal to zero and solve.  You get
  that $z = \pm 3\mathrm{i}$.  Plugging in again, we find the maximum
  modulus is 14.
- Geometry:  This polynomial is $(z-(\mathrm{i}+\mathrm{i}\sqrt{2}))(z-(\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\sqrt{2}))$.  Taking the modulus, we realize the level sets are collections of points whose product of distances from two given point (the roots just found) are fixed.  These level sets are [Cassini ovals][3].  By symmetry, then, the maximum will be on the imaginary axis and it is no great challenge to realize it will be the one of $3\mathrm{i}$ and $-3\mathrm{i}$ that is farthest from the midpoint of the roots (which is $\mathrm{i}$).  Plugging $-3i$ back into the polynomial, we get that the maximum modulus is $14$, again.

**Here too we did not get maximum value using triangle inequality**

**Question No $4$**

> If $|Z-(3+4i)|=2$ then maximum value of $|Z|$ is

**Solution**
Using Triangle ineqaulity $ ||Z|-|3+4i||\leq |Z-(3+4i)|$

$\implies$ $||Z|-|3+4i|| \leq 2$

$\implies$ $\implies$ $ -2 \leq|Z|-|3+4i| \leq 2$

$\implies$ $\implies$ $-2+5||Z| \leq 2+5$

$\implies max(|Z|)=7$

**Here i got answer using triangle inequality**

**Final Doubt: I am a teacher my doubt is how to tell a class 12th students When to apply tringle inequality and when not?**

[Find the maximum value of $f(z)=|z^3-z+2|$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925214/find-the-maximum-value-of-fz-z3-z2-on-the-unit-circle-z-1)

[What is the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ on the unit disc $D=\{z \in \mathbb C:|z|\leq 1\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260177/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-fz-on-the-unit-disc-d-z-in-mathbb-cz)

[How do you find the maximum value of $|z^2 - 2iz+1|$ given that $|z|=3$, using triangle inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643412/how-do-you-find-the-maximum-value-of-z2-2iz1-given-that-z-3-using-t)

[Find the maximum of the value $f(z)=|z^3+3z+2i|$ if $|z|=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202438/find-the-maximum-of-the-value-fz-z33z2i-if-z-1)

Comment: For complex numbers and their absolute value you can always apply the triangle inequality. The problem is not when to apply it, but how to interpret what the inequality is giving. You obtained an upper bound. You can only say that that upper bound is the maximum, if that upper bound is attained.

Comment: then how do i confirm in exam that whatever i calculated is correct or not? When to check upper bound and when not?

Comment: The confirmation is solving the problem somehow. In Question 2, the Solution didn't really solve the problem. It found an upper bound. To solve the problem one needs to show, in addition, that that upper bound is attained. You either exhibit a concrete $z$ for which the value is $3$ or sometimes one can show that such a $z$ exists without constructing it explicitly. In that particular problem one can just show that for $z=i$ we get $3$ as value.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say. In question $1$, the value $z=2$ doesn't satisfy the restriction $|z|=1$.

Comment: sorry. Overlooked

Comment: so i can say that when $Z$ is in linear i can directly get answer using triangle inequality but in quadratic and cubic we must check its upper bound is attained or not?

Comment: Can you elaborate yours this statement? **show that such a z exists without constructing it explicitly**. I mean how to show without constructing it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 4.
I suggest drawing pictures whenever possible.
(A student feels great when she can *see* the answer.)
You got an upper bound, which you don't
know is the maximum value. This question is really about
the cartesian plane. You have a circle of radius 2 centered
at (3,4). The maximum (and minimum) distance points lie
on the line through the origin and the center of the circle.
(Justification: the line is normal to the circle when it crosses.)
Algebraically, the maximum distance of $7$ occurs at
$$(3,4)+2\cdot{1\over5}(3,4)={7\over5}(3,4)$$

Comment: I know how to get it using circle. Infact i always draw a diagram. But my doubt is how to tell her that in question $1$ she cannot apply triangle inequality to get maximum value . How to check its upper bound or maximum value